# How do I remove features from an API Platform project?

Tags: api-platform.com

I have implemented an app based on API-Platform (https://api-platform.com).
How can I remove support for ReactJS and GraphQL and so on?
All features I am currently not using.
Or is that necessary at all? (I am very new to this technology.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to not enable them. You can start a project from `symfony/skeleton` and then require with `composer require api` to install only the core. then you will be able to require each feature when you require them.

Keep in mind that the package proposed by api platform is a boilerplate to quickstart a project. If you need to fine tune, it is better to start a project from scratch